# How to make a download class in typescript?

Tags: class, typescript

i want to make my own download class in Typescript.
This is how it looks now:

```
export class Download {
private _name: string;

constructor() {
    this._name = "";
}

public get name(): string {
    if (this._name !== "") {
        return this._name
    } else {
        return "empty";
    }
}
public set name(new_name: string) {
    this._name = new_name;
}

public download(data: string) {
    let encodedUri = encodeURI(data);
    let link: HTMLAnchorElement = <HTMLAnchorElement> document.createElement("a");
    link.setAttribute("href", encodedUri);
    link.setAttribute("download", this._name);
    <HTMLAnchorElement> document.body.appendChild(link);

    link.click();
}
```

}

But when i want to execute this, i get this error: ReferenceError: document is not defined.

What did I made wrong?

Thanks in advance^^

Comment: Is that a runtime error? You are running it in the browser?

Comment: i start the "app" over node. And when i want to start this code i press the button (onclick).

Comment: The function `download`, is it executed in the browser or node?

Comment: I start download in browser

Comment: The `document` object should be available in a browser. Is there anything special about your environment?

Comment: No, there is nothing special :/ Just want to download that file with content. But i dont know what i'm doing wrong ._.

Answer (score -1):

If you paste the below code in the [Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html), it works.
So it seems like your code gets executed in the node scope, where document is not available.

```
class Download {
    private _name: string;

    constructor() {
        this._name = "testing";
        this.download("test.html");
    }

    public download(data: string) {
        let encodedUri = encodeURI(data);
        let link: HTMLAnchorElement = <HTMLAnchorElement>document.createElement("a");

        link.setAttribute("href", encodedUri);
        link.setAttribute("download", this._name);
        document.body.appendChild(link);

        link.click();
    }
}
let d = new Download();
```

That being said, I'm not sure that creating an invisible link and then clicking it programmatically is the recommended way to download a file :)